# an integral related with tensor

Tags: calculus, tensors

Prove that, ${\LARGE\int}_M d^4x\sqrt{|g|}A_{\mu\nu}(D^\mu B^\nu) = {\LARGE\oint}_{\partial M} d^3\sigma^\mu A_{\mu \nu}B^\nu - {\LARGE\int}_M d^4x\sqrt{|g|}(D^\mu A_{\mu \nu})B^\nu$, where $\partial M$ is the three-dimensional boundary of a four-dimensional manifold $M$; $d^3\sigma^\mu$ is a four dimensional vector perpendicular to $\partial M$, directing inside $M$, whose modulus is equal to the volume element of $\partial M$.

I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this one, all I have managed to figure out that $d^4x$ here signifies the volume element of four-dimensional space $dx^1dx^2dx^3dx^4$, and $D^\mu$ is the standard covariant differential operator, also $|g|$ is the determinant of metric tensor. But how can I use these ideas to prove the above integral ? Any help will be appreciated in this regard, and any physical interpretation of that problem will be also very helpful to me.

Comment: Actually, $\sqrt{|g|} d^4x$ is the volume element of the physical space. The part $d^4x$ is just the "volume" in the coordinate space. Polar coordinates in 2D will serve as an example: the area of an element is $r \, dr \, d\theta$. Here, $\sqrt{|g|} = r$ and $d^2x = dr \, d\theta.$

Comment: With "physical space" I mean the four-dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generalized [Stoke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem#General_formulation) to show this. First, note that

$$
\color{blue}{D^\mu(A_{\mu\nu}B^{\nu})} = \color{red}{(D^\mu A_{\mu\nu} )B^\nu} + \color{orange}{A_{\mu\nu}(D^\mu B^\nu)}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_M {\rm d}^4 x~ \sqrt{|g|}\color{orange}{A_{\mu\nu}(D^\mu B^\nu)} &=& \int_M {\rm d}^4 x~ \sqrt{|g|}\color{blue}{D^\mu(A_{\mu\nu}B^{\nu})} -\int_M {\rm d}^4 x~ \sqrt{|g|}\color{red}{(D^\mu A_{\mu\nu} )B^\nu} \\
&=& \int_{\partial M} {\rm d}^3 x \sqrt{|h|} \sigma^\mu (A_{\mu\nu}B^{\nu}) - \int_M {\rm d}^4 x~ \sqrt{|g|}(D^\mu A_{\mu\nu} )B^\nu
\end{eqnarray}

where $h$ represents the determinant of the metric on $\partial M$ resulting from pulling back the metric on $M$. For more details go to Eq. (9.68) of [this](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/lecturenotes_2012.pdf) reference